# PCA reverse giving wrong data

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pca, inverse

I made function that makes PCA from the data frame. Unfortunately reversed data is much different than original array. Maybe I missed some value using one of these functions? Perhaps everything is ok and it's just huge reconstruction error? What could go possibly wrong with that?

```py
def pca_preproc(df, features, target):
    features = df.columns.to_list()
    y = df.loc[:,[target]].values
    x = df.loc[:, features].values
    
    print("before: ", x)
    
    mu = np.mean(x, axis=0)
    
    scaler = StandardScaler()
    x = scaler.fit_transform(x)
    np.stack(x)
    pca = PCA(n_components=3)
    principalComponents = pca.fit_transform(x)
    principalDf = pd.DataFrame(data = principalComponents
                 , columns = ['principal component 1', 'principal component 2', 'principal component 3'])
    df = pd.concat([principalDf, df[target]], axis = 1)
    return df, pca, scaler, principalComponents, x, mu

def clean_df(col_list, dataframe, target):
    df = drop_cols_from_list(col_list, dataframe)
    features = df.columns.to_list()
    df, pca, scaler, principalComponents, x, mu = pca_preproc(df, features, target)
    return df, pca, scaler, principalComponents, x, mu

def reverse_PCA(df_, pca, scaler, principalComponents, x, mu):
    nComp = 3    
    x_scaled = np.dot(pca.transform(x)[:,:nComp], pca.components_[:nComp,:])
    x = scaler.inverse_transform(x_scaled)
    x += mu
    return x

#something

df_, pca, scaler, principalComponents, x, mu = clean_df(col_list_ex, df_test, 'Y_type')
x_reversed = reverse_PCA(df_, pca, scaler, principalComponents, x, mu)
print("after: ", x_reversed)
```

Results are like this:

```
before PCA and inverse:  [[-1.0e+00  2.5e-01  2.5e-01 ...  4.0e+00  3.0e+00  1.0e+00]
 [-1.0e+00  4.0e-01  4.0e-01 ...  4.0e+00  2.2e+02  2.0e+01]
 [ 1.2e-01  4.0e-01  4.0e-01 ...  4.0e+00  3.0e+00  1.0e+00]
 ...
 [ 1.0e-01  3.0e-01  3.0e-01 ...  4.0e+00  3.0e+00  1.0e+00]
 [ 1.0e-01  3.5e-01  3.0e-01 ...  4.0e+00  2.8e+01  2.0e+00]
 [ 1.0e-01  3.5e-01  3.0e-01 ...  4.0e+00  3.0e+00  1.0e+00]]

after:  [[ 1.87032497e-01  5.88464904e-01  6.08126246e-01 ...  7.17782159e+00
  -4.08549763e+02 -9.15300495e+00]
 [ 2.03119648e-01  7.48578385e-01  7.77710789e-01 ...  7.29413940e+00
  -1.34419799e+02 -1.68119566e+00]
 [ 2.47774164e-01  6.60036640e-01  6.86949062e-01 ...  7.06887154e+00
   9.71677523e+01  6.75240674e+00]
 ...
 [ 2.82698305e-01  5.63887771e-01  5.86198477e-01 ...  6.73725489e+00
   1.39536210e+02  8.47227667e+00]
 [ 3.13501239e-01  6.05507702e-01  6.31709615e-01 ...  6.68114447e+00
   3.95724489e+02  1.64500613e+01]
 [ 3.08501171e-01  6.26582097e-01  6.53663567e-01 ...  6.72089238e+00
   3.83548448e+02  1.58648739e+01]]
```

Comment: What data are you using? Can you post a sample or provide a basic summary (e.g. number of features, correlation between features, etc)? If your data dimensionality is greater than 3 then it is not unreasonable that you would have some reconstruction error since you are only using 3 principal components.